# Need help in manipulating gridview during databound

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a table in the itemtemplate of a gridview.

My requirement is something like what's shown in the below link

http://img253.imageshack.us/img253/5987/requirement.jpg

i.e. Say 3, 4 and 5 are user id's. 
The middle column can contain some information about that user.
Say for User 3 we have Info 1, Info 2 and Info 3 in those three rows.
Similarly, for user 4 and 5, we would have some values in the middle column.

The number of rows in the middle column can vary. It depends on the number of rows 
returned by the DB call for that user.

So, how can I achieve  this using grid view?

Will it be possible for me to add rows in the databound event dynamically by looking 
at the previous or next row in the datasource? If so, how should I go about it?

Or is there an easier/better way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a literal control in the itemtemplate field for the middle column and bind it on rowdatabound event with dynamic created table with the user data.

Comment: Hmm....If Info1, Info2 and Info3 were in the same row (different columns) in the dataset, I could have done that. But, they are on three different rows. I need some kind of mechanism wherein I can compare the current row's user id with that of the previous row and if they match, insert the info information of the current row along with the previous rows info.

Comment: Hey mate....Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Have achieved the requirement using your suggestion. Literals!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to maybe think about using a Repeater to generate the outer table and perhaps embed a Gridview into each row to do the detail - I think this might give you a bit more flexibility in your layout.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserID") %>' runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```